# how to escape HTML entity when used character_limiter in codeignite3?

Tags: codeigniter

I've using **character_limiter**  in codeigniter to limit text which I selected from data and that text were input by TinyMCE editor so my text will contain with html character and another **css** that why my result is wrong because Character_limiter will count all the character both text and html code.

So I want to know how to escape all HTML or any code from my text and limited below function

Here is my Model

```
 public function content() {

        $this->load->helper('text');
        $this->promot = $this->my_model->all_selct('*', 'content', array('status' => 1, 'lang' => $this->langs, 'home'=>1), FALSE);

        if ($this->promot) {
            $out = '';
            foreach ($this->promot as $item) {
                $text = html_entity_decode($item['text']);
                $out .= '<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-xs-6" style="padding:0px; !important">'; // animated bounceIn
                $out .= '<div style=" " class="thumbnail mgrid">'; // animated bounceIn
                $out .= '<a href ="' . base_url($this->cleanstr($item['slug']). '/'.$item['cid']).'" >';
//                $out .= '<img src ="' . base_url('assets/img/content/' . $item['img']) . '"class="img-responsive">';
                $out .= '<div class ="hom_img">';
                $out .= '<h3 class="text-left">' . $item['name'] . '</h3></a>';
                $out .= '<p class="himg">'.character_limiter($text, 50) . '  </p>';
                $out .='</div>';
                $out .='</div>';
                $out .='</div>';
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return $out;
    }
```

Comment: take the input use strip_tags() then count length of string .

Comment: No if I used this function I will lost some of my text

Comment: you want to display only 50 characters and it shud exclude html tags??

Comment: Yes that right I don't want to include HTML tags